# Server Side Playlist for Flash Media Server

Tags: flash, media, server-side, flash-media-server, playlists

How do you create a Server Side Playlist for Flash Media Server that will play a list of files from a directory, e.g., a list of MP4 or F4v files?  In particular, in what directories do you place the MAIN.ASC and MEDIA files and what additional settings are required by FMS? Lastly, how would you like to it via a browser or stream?

The documentation (from Adobe) is rather vague in this regard.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

To create the server side playlist first we need to write the .asc file which will be hosted on the application folder of the fms hosted server.

For creating the playlist on server side we need to use the Stream Class.

`

```
application.onAppStart = function()
{

 application.myStream = Stream.get("playlist"); 

if(application.myStream) 
 { 
    application.myStream.play("01",0,-1,true);

 }
}
```

`